# Rails.logger does not log in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and I want to use the logger.

So I wrote:

```
Rails.logger.error '123'
```

But when I run it (I am sure that it runs because there are other commands in the same method that are being executed) I don't see any log. Neither in the terminal where the server (rails s) runs, nor in my log/development.log file.

What could be happening here?

Comment: I just tested. It's fine. Maybe attach more information to the post. Other people could help you.

Comment: yep, can't reproduce. What is `Rails.logger`? Maybe it's set to write to `/dev/null` or something.

Comment: Check `config.log_level` value in your environment configuration file